# How find the minimum of the value $n$ such$105\mid \left(9^{p^2}-29^p+n\right)$

Tags: number-theory

Find the minimum of the value $n$,such for any 
prime number $p>3$,have 
$$105\mid\left(9^{p^2}-29^p+n\right)$$

My since $$105=5\times 3\times 7$$

so
$$9^{p^2}-29^p+n=(10-1)^{p^2}-(30-1)^{p}+n)\equiv (-1)^{p^2}-(-1)^{p}+n \pmod 5$$

then I can't.Thank you

Comment: Your calculation gives progress, it says that $n\equiv 0\pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 3):

Where you have left off, $$F=9^{p^2}-29^p+n\equiv n\pmod5$$

For $5|F,$
$$ n\equiv0\pmod5\  \ \ \ (1)$$

Similarly, $$9^{p^2}-29^p+n\equiv -(-1)^p+n\equiv1+n\implies n\equiv-1\pmod3\  \ \ \ (2)$$

But $p\equiv\pm1\pmod3\implies p^2\equiv1\implies p^2=3a+1 $ some integer $a$

$$2^{p^2}=2^{3a+1}=2(2^3)^a\equiv2\cdot1^a\pmod7\equiv2$$

$$\implies F\equiv2^{p^2}-1^p+n\equiv2-1+n\pmod7\iff n\equiv-1\pmod7\  \ \ \ (3)$$

If my calculation is correct, $(2),(3)\implies n\equiv-1\pmod{21}\ \ \ \ (4)$

Then apply CRT or Euclid GCD formula on $(1),(4)$

Comment: +1 Nice solution.  Btw, for latex you can use \tag{1} to label equations.